# How do I use an AND statement with SELECT DISTINCT?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select distinct based on two columns so that if either of the two columns has the same value, then it will only post that row once. If it helps you understand, I am doing a sender/receiver thing and I only want to pull one row (whether it be sender or receiver).

Here is how I want the MySQL to work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(sender AND receiver), message, timestamp  
FROM messages 
WHERE receiver=receiver_name OR sender=sender_name;
```

Example:

Messages Table:

```
id|  sender |receiver | message                | timestamp
1 | Jeffrey | Michael | Hey man, what's up     | 12:00 PM  
2 | Michael | Jeffrey | Not much. How are you? | 12:02 PM
```

Result after SQL query:

Latest message from Michael: Not much. How are you? Time: 12:02 PM

I hope that makes some sense

Comment: What are your desired results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the OP comment to the answer of Gordon Linoff it seems he is interested to retrieve the last message to every conversione between he and someone else, in that case the sender or the receiver will be him

```
SET @myname = 'Michael' --just stick here your name

SELECT m.*
FROM   messages m
       INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(ID) ID
                   FROM   messages
                   WHERE  @myname IN (receiver, sender)
                   GROUP BY COALESCE(NULLIF(receiver, @myname), sender)
                  ) a ON m.ID = a.ID
```

The formula `COALESCE(NULLIF(receiver, @myname), sender)` will always resolve in the other name:

- if the OP is the sender then `NULLIF(receiver, @myname)` will return the receiver and so will the `COALESCE`
- if the OP is the receiver then `NULLIF(receiver, @myname)` will return `NULL` and `COALESCE` will return the sender

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the concat function.

```
SELECT distinct concat(sender,receiver)
FROM messages
WHERE receiver=receiver_name OR sender=sender_name;
```

See [here](http://www.mysql.com/about/contact/) for more info.

Comment: Will that also return the message and timestamp values?

Comment: The query qives you the distinct values, if those values are duplicated however have different date time values, you need to get the last record based on the MAX(timestamp) value.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code -

```
SELECT DISTINCT(sender AND receiver), message, timestamp 
FROM messages 
WHERE receiver=receiver_name OR sender=sender_name;
```

New code here -

```
SELECT DISTINCT (sender , receiver), message, timestamp  
FROM messages 
WHERE .........
```

Comment: That returns nothing. I need the distincts to be isolated, otherwise if you have sent or a received a message from the same person nothing will be returned

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use `least()` and `greatest()`:

```
select distinct least(sender, receiver), greatest(sender, receiver)
from messages;
```

If you want the most recent timestamp, use `group by`:

```
select least(sender, receiver), greatest(sender, receiver),
       max(timestamp)
from messages
group by least(sender, receiver), greatest(sender, receiver);
```

EDIT:

If you want information about the last message a person sent or received, you can do:

```
select m.*
from messages m
where not exists (select 1
                  from messages m2
                  where (m2.sender = m.sender or m2.receiver = m.receiver or
                         m2.receiver = m.receiver or m2.receiver = m.sender
                        ) and
                        m2.timestamp > m.timestamp
                 );
```

Comment: It just displays every single message. I only want to display one message per person (the last message they sent).

Comment: This almost works, but it just displays one message from one user. I want to display one message from every user that has messaged me.